# How to use embedded Fonts to call the Graphics2D.drawString(...) with iText (DefaultFontMapper?)

Tags: java, itext

To generate a valid PDF/X document, it's mandatory to have all fonts embedded. Somehow it's not possible for me to use those fonts in an Graphics2D context.

This Unittests shows the problem (commented lines are some tests i made):

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.itextpdf.awt.DefaultFontMapper;
import com.itextpdf.awt.DefaultFontMapper.BaseFontParameters;
import com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class TestFont
{

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToAddFountsAndDrawOnCanvas() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException
    {
        final DefaultFontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
        mapper.insertDirectory(".");

        final PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(System.out);
        for (final Entry<String, BaseFontParameters> entry : mapper.getMapper().entrySet())
        {
            out2.println(String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().fontName));
        }
        out2.flush();

        final float width = 150;
        final float height = 150;

        final Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(width, height));
        final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("fonts.pdf"));
        writer.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFX32002);

        document.open();
        final Graphics2D g2d = new PdfGraphics2D(writer.getDirectContent(), width, height, mapper);

        g2d.setFont(new Font("Comicate", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        g2d.drawString("Hello world", 5, 24);

        g2d.dispose();

        document.close();
    }

}
```

It will throw an `PdfXConformanceException` with message: "All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica.

I already browsed though the `PdfGraphics2D` class to check the `setFont()` implementation and found out, that a `FontMapper` will be used. I already added this to the Unittest above.

```
public void setFont(Font f) {
    if (f == null)
        return;
    if (onlyShapes) {
        font = f;
        return;
    }
    if (f == font)
        return;
    font = f;
    fontSize = f.getSize2D();
    baseFont = getCachedBaseFont(f);
}

private BaseFont getCachedBaseFont(Font f) {
    synchronized (baseFonts) {
        BaseFont bf = (BaseFont)baseFonts.get(f.getFontName());
        if (bf == null) {
            bf = fontMapper.awtToPdf(f);
            baseFonts.put(f.getFontName(), bf);
        }
        return bf;
    }
}
```

The Unittest is based on [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=261) from the iText in Action book. [Here](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=457) are some other examples about the FontMapper.

To run the Unittest you need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The Custom Font (located in ".") you find [here](http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Comicate.htm).

The Console Output shows me this (to identify the fontName):

```
Comicate: ./COMICATE.TTF
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the exact way to correct the error in your code, but there are easy workarounds:

Workaround 1) Create a BufferedImage to do all your graphics painting to. Then you can use all normal `java.awt.Graphics` functions like `drawString` and `setColor` regardless of iText, and when you are done just draw the image to a PDF. WARNING you do loose quality of text when zooming, but here is an example:

```
//create doccument and writer    
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(200, 100);
Document document= new Document(pagesize);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\sample.pdf"));

BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(BorderWidth, BorderHeight, BorderWidth);
//Do all graphics code here, draw strings and images etc
    //Some code to set font (java.awt.Font)
    //Some code to draw string
    //Some code to draw image?

//Convert BufferedImage to Image
Image img = (Image)bf;
//draw image to PDF using writer
writer.getDirectContentUnder().addImage(img);
```

Workaround 2) This uses iText features to draw strings, without needing to create any graphics objects, the font is taken care of by using a `BaseFont` as follows:

```
//create doccument and writer    
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(200, 100);
Document document= new Document(pagesize);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\sample.pdf"));

document.open();
//This sample uses the "GOTHIC.TTF" font file located in the "Template" package
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(GUI.class.getClass().getResource("/Template/GOTHIC.TTF") + "", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

//set font type, size and color
Font font = new Font(bf, 13.5f);

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

canvas.beginText();
canvas.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
//Method Usage: showTextAligned(Align, String, x, y, rotation);
canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_TOP, "My Text Here", 75, 40, 0);
canvas.endText();

document.close();
```

I know this does not give the answer you were looking for, however if you are just drawing a small amount of text then workaround 2 works great, I have used something similar to workaround 2 before. If this does not help then I am sure Bruno will have the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank for your suggestion. Sadly i can't make use of you workarounds :(. It's not me calling the g2d.drawText(...), it's JFreechart.

Comment: Could you take a look at the question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 1):

By defining new BaseFont(s) and implementing the interface of FontMapper() >>> public BaseFont awtToPdf(java.awt.Font font). This will apply the awt.font(s) as embedded into the pdf.

In the example below I "print" g2D (including "drawString" method), drawn in outer class. The result is exported vector pdf with embedded "ArialMT" and "Arial-BoldMT" fonts only.

[preview img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzyvH.jpg)

```
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
    try {
        pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();
        BaseFont fontRegular = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial_0.ttf", "Cp1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        BaseFont fontBold = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd_0.ttf", "Cp1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        FontMapper fontMapper = new FontMapper() {

            @Override
            public java.awt.Font pdfToAwt(BaseFont arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BaseFont awtToPdf(java.awt.Font font) {
                if (font.equals(Fonts.getFontRegular10()) || font.equals(Fonts.getFontRegular12())){
                    return fontRegular;
                }
                else {
                    return fontBold;
                }
            }
        };
        PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(MainFrame.getFRAME_WIDTH(), MainFrame.getFRAME_HEIGHT());
        Graphics2D g2D = new PdfGraphics2D(template, MainFrame.getFRAME_WIDTH(), MainFrame.getFRAME_HEIGHT(), fontMapper);
        MainFrame.getPanel().print(g2D);
        g2D.dispose();
        cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        document.close();
    }
```

Comment: the only working solution for creating a PDF with `itext` , placing the .tff files inside the runnable Jar